# ActiveMQ Artemis and 5.x listeners at same time - NullPointerException

Tags: java, activemq-classic, spring-jms, activemq-artemis

I have a legacy Spring 4.2.1.RELEASE application that connects to ActiveMQ 5.x as a listener and now we're adding connectivity to ActiveMQ Artemis. For Artemis we're using durable subscriptions because we don't want message loss on a topic when the subscribers go down and shared subscriptions because we wanted the option of clustering or using concurrency to asynchronously process the messages in the subscription. I have separate `ConnectionFactory`s and `ListenerContainer`s, but from this `WARN` log that keeps repeating it looks like the Artemis DMLC can't start due to the following NPE:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.createConsumer(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:856)
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractPollingMessageListenerContainer.createListenerConsumer(AbstractPollingMessageListenerContainer.java:213)
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageListenerInvoker.initResourcesIfNecessary(DefaultMessageListenerContainer.java:1173)
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageListenerInvoker.invokeListener(DefaultMessageListenerContainer.java:1149)
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageListenerInvoker.executeOngoingLoop(DefaultMessageListenerContainer.java:1142)
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageListenerInvoker.run(DefaultMessageListenerContainer.java:1039)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

On the surface it looks like it can't find the method `createSharedDurableConsumer`.  Looking at the [AbstractMessageListenerContainer](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/v4.2.1.RELEASE/spring-jms/src/main/java/org/springframework/jms/listener/AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java) I have, line 856 is calling method.invoke

```java
/** The JMS 2.0 Session.createSharedDurableConsumer method, if available */
private static final Method createSharedDurableConsumerMethod = ClassUtils.getMethodIfAvailable(
        Session.class, "createSharedDurableConsumer", Topic.class, String.class, String.class);

...

Method method = (isSubscriptionDurable() ?
                        createSharedDurableConsumerMethod : createSharedConsumerMethod);
try {
    return (MessageConsumer) method.invoke(session, destination, getSubscriptionName(), getMessageSelector());
}
```

Artemis configuration:

```java
@Configuration
public class ArtemisConfig {

    @Autowired
    private Environment env;

    @Bean
    public ConnectionFactory artemisConnectionFactory() {
        ActiveMQConnectionFactory artemisConnectionFactory = ActiveMQJMSClient
                .createConnectionFactoryWithHA(JMSFactoryType.CF, createTransportConfigurations());

        artemisConnectionFactory.setUser(env.getRequiredProperty("artemis.username"));
        artemisConnectionFactory.setPassword(env.getRequiredProperty("artemis.password"));
        artemisConnectionFactory.setCallTimeout(env.getRequiredProperty("artemis.call.timeout.millis", Long.class));
        artemisConnectionFactory.setConnectionTTL(env.getRequiredProperty("artemis.connection.ttl.millis", Long.class));
        artemisConnectionFactory
                .setCallFailoverTimeout(env.getRequiredProperty("artemis.call.failover.timeout.millis", Long.class));
        artemisConnectionFactory.setInitialConnectAttempts(
                env.getRequiredProperty("artemis.connection.attempts.initial", Integer.class));
        artemisConnectionFactory
                .setReconnectAttempts(env.getRequiredProperty("artemis.connection.attempts.reconnect", Integer.class));
        artemisConnectionFactory.setRetryInterval(env.getRequiredProperty("artemis.retry.interval.millis", Long.class));
        artemisConnectionFactory
                .setRetryIntervalMultiplier(env.getRequiredProperty("artemis.retry.interval.multiplier", Double.class));
        artemisConnectionFactory.setBlockOnAcknowledge(true);
        artemisConnectionFactory.setBlockOnDurableSend(true);
        artemisConnectionFactory.setCacheDestinations(true);
        artemisConnectionFactory.setConsumerWindowSize(0);
        artemisConnectionFactory.setMinLargeMessageSize(1024 * 1024);

        CachingConnectionFactory cachingConnectionFactory = new CachingConnectionFactory(artemisConnectionFactory);

        cachingConnectionFactory
        .setSessionCacheSize(env.getRequiredProperty("artemis.session.cache.size", Integer.class));
        cachingConnectionFactory.setReconnectOnException(true);

        return cachingConnectionFactory;
    }

    @Bean
    public DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory artemisContainerFactory(ConnectionFactory artemisConnectionFactory,
            JmsTransactionManager artemisJmsTransactionManager,
            MappingJackson2MessageConverter mappingJackson2MessageConverter) {
        DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory factory = new DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory();

        factory.setCacheLevel(DefaultMessageListenerContainer.CACHE_CONSUMER);
        factory.setConnectionFactory(artemisConnectionFactory);
        factory.setDestinationResolver(new DynamicDestinationResolver());
        factory.setMessageConverter(mappingJackson2MessageConverter);
        factory.setSubscriptionDurable(Boolean.TRUE);
        factory.setSubscriptionShared(Boolean.TRUE);
        factory.setSessionAcknowledgeMode(Session.SESSION_TRANSACTED);
        factory.setSessionTransacted(Boolean.TRUE);
        factory.setTransactionManager(artemisJmsTransactionManager);

        return factory;
    }

    private TransportConfiguration[] createTransportConfigurations() {
        String connectorFactoryFqcn = NettyConnectorFactory.class.getName();
        Map<String, Object> primaryTransportParameters = new HashMap<>(2, 1F);
        String primaryHostname = env.getRequiredProperty("artemis.primary.hostname");
        Integer primaryPort = env.getRequiredProperty("artemis.primary.port", Integer.class);

        primaryTransportParameters.put("host", primaryHostname);
        primaryTransportParameters.put("port", primaryPort);

        return new TransportConfiguration[] {
                new TransportConfiguration(connectorFactoryFqcn, primaryTransportParameters),
                new TransportConfiguration(connectorFactoryFqcn, backupTransportParameters) };
    }
}
```

My pom uses version 2.10.0 of Artemis.

How do I fix this?

Comment: In the version of AbstractMessageListenerContainer I have, line 856 is calling `method.invoke` on the method.  Updating the question with the code showing this.

Comment: Updated the question with my connection factory and dmlc factory beans.  Haven't tried with a newer Spring version - This is a legacy application so we're trying to avoid doing something like that.

Comment: Sorry - The change we're making is to add a new Artemis listener.  That's what's not working.

Comment: Durable because we don't want message loss on a topic when the subscribers go down.  Shared because we wanted the option of clustering or using concurrency to asynchronously process (though we could probably get away without this if that fixed it)

Comment: Inspecting the `ConnectionFactory` being passed into my dmlc factory bean I see this: `[org.apache.geronimo.specs:geronimo-jms_1.1_spec:1.1.1]`.  Not sure if that means 2.0 isn't on the classpath.  I don't remember needing to add specific dependencies to my pom for jms specifications but maybe that's what I'm missing?

Comment: When comparing my external dependencies in this app with ones in a working application that listens to Artemis, it does appear to be missing the javax.jms-api dependency.  I'll try fixing that.

Comment: 4.2.x is no longer supported; 4.2.1 is over 5 years old. The current supported 4.x is 4.3.28 (through the end of this year only).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The JMS 2.0 spec is backwards compatible with JMS 1.1 so make sure you only have the JMS 2 spec on your classpath. My hunch is that the reflection calls in the Spring code are getting messed up because they're hitting the JMS 1.1 spec classes instead of the proper JMS 2 spec classes.

Comment: The ActiveMQ DMLC is connecting fine, it's my Artemis one (or the one I intended to be my Artemis one) that doesn't work.  Inspecting DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory, I looks like it's getting pulled in through spring-jms 4.2.1.RELEASE

Comment: Could this have something to do with having dependencies for both artemis-jms-client and activemq-core on top of spring jms or something?  Not sure if the wrong implementation of DMLC is being used.  At this point I'm grasping at straws.

Comment: I don't see how having those dependencies would be a problem.

Comment: Explicitly adding javax.jms-api to my pom and excluding the geronimo-jms_1.1_spec from activemq-pool and activemq-core in my pom fixed the issue.  Accepted answer.  Thank you!

Comment: Thanks, it was a lifesaver :)